# How to install SOLRNET

Tags: solrnet

Hi I am very new to SOLRNET.
Can you please explain where I can get the software of SOLRNET,how to install it.

Lucene in java has a port for .NEt right.So is this a port to Solr in java???

Thank you

Comment: You should mark Mauricio's answer as the accepted answer...

Answer (score 10):

> where I can get the software of SOLRNET

Download the binaries from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/SolrNet) or [newer binaries from the build server](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project36&guest=1) (recommended)

> how to install it.

Add a reference to SolrNet.dll in your project, then see the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) for information on how to use it in your project.

> So is this a port to Solr in java

No, it's a *client* for the Solr *server*. You still need the Solr server. If you want to run Solr without a Java runtime, you might be interested in [this article](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/02/running-solr-on-net.html) I wrote recently.

Comment: TFS :) 
This is what I've understood if you say it is just a client:
SOLRNET is just another layer using .NET on the existing SOLR (java).It provides library in .NET to access solr and it can provide all the features that Solr(java) provides. Am I right !!!!

Comment: @Nakkala: if you have doubts about the client/server concept see http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/client_server_architecture.html

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, the link to build server seems down, could you please update the link

Comment: @NewHire that's the link, it's only down temporarily. See https://twitter.com/codebetterCI for status updates.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, Could you please take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21688218/2711965) and thanks for the link

Comment: @NewHire https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/solrnet