# How to get Started with Solr.NET

Tags: asp.net, solrnet

Hey I was wondering how to get started with Solr.NET even the basics what files to download etc, I checked the net ofcourse but its like every site saying something different some are older so just not sure.

Cheers

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking specifically about the client library? Or also setting up the Solr server? Because Solr.NET itself has some pretty good docs and samples on its homepage http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/

Comment: Hey ash thanks for your reply. I am wondering how to set up a basic search with Solr.Net what Do I need to install on my server ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See these questions:

- [Is Solr available for .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749314/is-solr-available-for-net)
- [How to install SOLRNET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088865/how-to-install-solrnet)

See [SolrNet docs](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet), it contains several code samples.

And if you're just starting out with Solr, see the Solr [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html) and [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FrontPage).