# How to use Solrnet with my .Net Application

Tags: asp.net, solrnet

while I am new with solrnet. I want to play with this in my .net application. I already have Github Solrnet project with me which contains some .cs file. Any guidelines to use these method. I know this may be vast but I need start-up with it.

Any helpful link for start-up

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Started with Solr.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646615/how-to-get-started-with-solr-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the sample application running from https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Sample-application.md

This is the best place to start with. Get the sample application running then copy over the code that you need from the sample app to your application. Once you have the sample app data running in your app then you can modify this to suit your needs.

Is there any particular area you are stuck at? It may be easier to answer specific issues you are having with your app.