# How to integrate solr full text search engine in asp.net

Tags: solr, full-text-search, solrnet

How to integrate solr net in asp.net site. I am new and having little idea. After searching on google i am confused from where i should start. Please refer me some ref. link from where i can do this in better way. Thakns.

Comment: You need to learn Solr, which you can easily operate with it's REST interface. Then you need a Solr binding for .Net; SolrNet is discussed here often.

Comment: yes now i found many other question for same.

Comment: but is there any direct method to parse response from solr search engine to a object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088865/how-to-install-solrnet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646615/how-to-get-started-with-solr-net http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to use [SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet). It has the capability to parse a Solr response into a .Net object. Please see the examples on the SolrNet site for examples of how to setup the library to query and parse the responses. Also, if you check out the [SolrNet source code on GitHub](http://github.com/mausch/solrnet), it includes a sample ASP.NET MVC application that shows a great examples of using the library. Please note that if you do not have an MVC site, the code shown in the sample app can be applied in a Web Forms application.