# Solr.Net query returning false results

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I am trying to search Solr Instance with [Solr.Net](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet). I have field `body` which is defined in schema as:

```
<field name="body" 
       type="text_general" 
       indexed="true" 
       stored="true" 
       omitNorms="true"/>
```

`text_general` uses `solr.StandardTokenizerFactory` in schema and defined as:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

(I haven't changed anything with this field type, It is the one I got with the default installation of solr)

I am trying to query records against search term `LISTBU5.RCV`, it is returning me results containing `LISTBU4.RCV`. Like:

```
Items left on queue: \\111.11.11.11\Lists\SAVELIST\ABC2\LISTBU4.RCV
```

**False Result:** The number at the end of the search term is different

My code for querying is:

```
SolrQueryByField solrQuery = new SolrQueryByField("body", searchTerm);

var result = solr.Query(solrQuery, new SolrNet.Commands.Parameters.QueryOptions
{
    Rows = 100, // 
    Start = 0,
    OrderBy = new[] { new SortOrder("ID", Order.DESC) },
});
```

But if I use Text Query like:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery("(body:" + "\"" + searchTerm + "\")");
```

It returns exact results. I know that creating a Text query is not encouraged in `Solr.Net` but what should I do about it ?

I am using `SolrNet.dll` version `0.4.0.2002` with Solr Instance `4.4.0` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to find the problem. The reason I was getting the false result was because of the `SortOrder` specified in my query options. It was overriding the default SortOrder based on relevance score. I just modified my query options like:

```
var result = solr.Query(solrQuery, new SolrNet.Commands.Parameters.QueryOptions
{
    Rows = 100, // 
    Start = 0,
    OrderBy = new[] { new SortOrder("score", Order.DESC), new SortOrder("ID", Order.DESC) },
});
```

`new SortOrder("score", Order.DESC)` will force the results to be returned based on relevance score first and then it will do the sorting based on the ID.

I am not really sure why `SortOrder` was overridden when sending a text query to SOLR. But this seems to work since it will select top 100 rows with exact term instead of false positives.

I will just leave this answer for future visitors, and will accept any future answer if it provides reason for this search behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the two queries were different because of the term was **tokenized** in the 1st example but not the second, which was protected by double quote.  Would you mind to try:

```
SolrQueryByField solrQuery = new SolrQueryByField("body", "\""+searchTerm+"\"");
```

This might give you the same result as the 2nd query(if not consider the ordering). HIH

Comment: with simple text query it works as expected, I specified that in my question as well. In Solr Web UI if I get the expected result as well. It is only `SolrQueryByField` which was not giving the proper result. I believe I have found the solution and posted the same as answer.